# Ansible & Jinja 2 templates - vars .yml additions

Tags: ansible, jinja2, cisco

First spin with Ansible and I'm trying to do a relatively basic thing. I have created a Jinja2 template to output a configuration for a Nexus switch. It seems to work fine. I am following the folder structure where the top directory is the 'role' and within that directory are subdirectories of 'tasks' , 'templates', and 'vars'. Under the 'vars' directory I have one file named main.yml as I understand it should be. What I'd like to have is multiple vars files that contain various different elements so I can make the whole thing more modular.

Here are a few configs I have currently:

**The playbook I run in the top directory:**

```
    ---
    - name: Apply tor role   
      gather_facts: no   
      hosts: localhost

      roles:
        - tor
```

**tor/tasks/main.yml file**

```
    - name: Generate Configs
      template: src={{ item.profile }}.j2 dest=staging/drc/{{ item.hostname }}/{{ item.hostname }}.cfg
      with_items: "{{ switches }}"
```

**And a snippet of the main.yml file in the vars directory:**

```
---
  switches:
    - hostname: 5K01
      profile: nxos_template
      mgmt_ip: 10.20.90.9/24
      vlans:
      - {vlan_name: LegacyData, vlan_number: '5'}
      - {vlan_name: Voice, vlan_number: '20'}
      - {vlan_name: Data_Center, vlan_number: '50'}
      - {vlan_name: Vmotion, vlan_number: '51'}
      - {vlan_name: Citrix, vlan_number: '52'}
      - {vlan_name: Citrix_XEN, vlan_number: '56'}
      - {vlan_name: Citrix_Green_Infrastructure, vlan_number: '61'}
      - {vlan_name: Citrix_Red_Ingrastructure, vlan_number: '62'}
      - {vlan_name: Citrix_Green_XenApp, vlan_number: '63'}
      - {vlan_name: Citrix_Yellow, vlan_number: '64'}
      - {vlan_name: Citrix_Red_Desktops, vlan_number: '68'}
      - {vlan_name: Zerto-VRA-Network, vlan_number: '90'}
      - {vlan_name: Management, vlan_number: '92'}
      - {vlan_name: PCI_FW_Intermediate_Network, vlan_number: '121'}
      features:
        - nxapi
        - interface-vlan
        - hsrp
        - lacp
        - vpc
        - eigrp
        - npiv
        - fcoe
        - fport-channel-trunk
        - dhcp
        - fex
        - lldp
```

I would like to remove the vlans: dict to another vars file named vlans.yml. I figure I'd place that in the same directory as the current main.yml vars file and call the vlans.yml file out somewhere. I've tried to use the 'include_vars:' option but it won't take, specifically gives me an error when it is used within the same block as the 'template:' action.

Comment: How you're importing that vlan.yml vars file? It should work fine on this scenario you described. Basically you should need only to `include_vars: vars/vlans.yml`.

Comment: I've tried. I I place that into the playbook I get "ERROR! 'include_vars' is not a valid attribute for a Play"

Comment: The playbook is the first set of code I have above. It has the name "Apply tor role"

Comment: Is your vlans.yml in `roles/tor/vars`? If not, paste it there. Then in your `tor/tasks/main.yml` you include your vlans.yml var file like this: `- include_vars: vars/vlans.yml`. It will work. When you said you got `ERROR! 'include_vars' is not a valid attribute for a Play`, I think you included on your playbook but the way you're using it will not allow you to include it there. So you must include on your role tasks main, this will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it there as well. I get a different error when trying to run " ERROR! conflicting action statements: include_vars, template". I inserted include_vars: var/vlans.yml under " - name: Generate Configs" in the tor/tasks/main.yml file. Tried it on it's own line and got errors as well. Seems to recognize the vlans.yml file but it doesn't apply it to the configurations.

Comment: It seems syntax or identation error now... For each task you must have a `-` in line beggining...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question, yes. You can move those info without problems to a new file.

Lets suppose you have a main.yml and vlans.yml vars file and this is your playbook as you posted:

```
---
- name: Apply tor role   
  gather_facts: no   
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - tor
```

This should be your file structure:

```
$ tree roles/
roles/
└── tor
    ├── tasks
    │   └── main.yml
    └── vars
        ├── main.yml
        └── vlans.yml
```

And for your role `tor`, you need to import that `vlans.yml` vars:

```
- name: include vlans variable file
  include_vars: vars/vlans.yml

- name: Generate Configs
  template: src={{ item.profile }}.j2 dest=staging/drc/{{ item.hostname }}/{{ item.hostname }}.cfg
  with_items: "{{ switches }}"
```

Comment: Looks like the file is imported and the variables are available now, but how do I access them from the template? currently I'm using the "with_items: "{{ switches }}" which is pulling from the main.yml vars file. When I remove the vlans data from the main.yml file, it gives me an error saying that the 'dict object has no attribute vlans' which is understandable since it can't find that value. In the Jinja2 template, I call the variables like this : {% for vlan in item.vlans %} etc... is this not the way?

Comment: I guess the question is; can I use a single template against multiple vars files? I am going to test that I can create a vlan.j2 template and pass a separate vars file to it, I suspect it will work but I'd much rather have a single template.